# Error using Dexie from browser extension content scripts

Tags: typescript, firefox-addon-webextensions, dexie, web-ext

I'm facing an error when I run the [Dexie Hello World](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js#hello-world-typescript) from the content script of my firefox extension.

The extension is:

- in typescript
- compiled using `webpack` + `babbel`
- runned using `web-ext run`.

The previously linked example is declared in the manifest.json as `content_scripts` and the storage permission is set.

I think the problem is related to the extension environment , because when I paste the code compiled by webpack into the browser console it works a expected.

The error: `OpenFailedError: TypeError "then" is read-only`

Versions:

- `Dexie.js`: `3.0.3`
- `web-ext`: `5.5.0`
- `firefox`: `86.0`

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Use it in the background script and send the result via messaging.

Comment: Ah! yupe that's working. thanks.

Comment: Is that due to a lack of permission from the content script ?